# How to restrict initial pool size in hikaricp?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I used to have a `tomcat` connection pool configuration restricting the initial pool size: `spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=2`

Now switching to `hikaricp`: what is the equivalent to restrict the initially started connections?

Sidenote: `spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle` does not prevent initializing 10 connections at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out it had to do with my configuration of multiple datasources.

In general, the property `spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=2` automatically restricts the startup pool size correctly!

But if having multiple data sources, there was a configuration property missing, as follows:

```
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.secondary.hikari")
    public DataSource secondatyDataSource() {
        return ...
    }
```

Before I just had `"spring.datasource.secondary"`, and there by my property `"spring.datasource.secondary.hikari.*"` was not taken into account.

This is probably wrong documented in
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Comment: Nice finding. Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 10):

You can use these properties provided in spring boot:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=8
```

and then:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=120000
```

to limit the life of idle connections, but hikari doesn't give you such property for initial number of connections.

Answer (score 6):

With spring boot, set these properties in your application.properties.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
```