# java.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected in Spring Batch

Tags: oracle, spring-batch, hikaricp

I am working `Spring Batch` project which reads data from `Oracle` and Write it into DB, when I run the batch job, it gives me below error.

I went through many links like: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1202 and https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1106 and https://jira.sakaiproject.org/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/SAK-38852/SAK-38852.html, but not sure how to fit it.

jav

```
a.lang.Exception: Apparent connection leak detected
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:612) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:763) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JdbcPagingItemReader.java:224) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:110) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:93) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.4.RELEASE.jar:5.2.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.PostgresMongoContactsMigrationApplication.run(PostgresMongoContactsMigrationApplication.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:784) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.5.RELEASE.jar:2.2.5.RELEASE]
    at com.example.PostgresMongoContactsMigrationApplication.main(PostgresMongoContactsMigrationApplication.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
```

Code

```
@Bean(name = "oracleDataSource")
public DataSource oracleDataSource() {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.url"));
    hikariConfig.setUsername(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.username"));
    hikariConfig.setPassword(env.getProperty("oracle.datasource.password"));

    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(70);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("oracle CP");
    hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(300000);
    hikariConfig.setLeakDetectionThreshold(60 * 1000);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTimeout(120 * 1000);

    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}
```

Reader

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> employeeReader() throws Exception{
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Employee> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
    reader.setSql(EMP_SQL);
    reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
    reader.setFetchSize(5000);
    reader.setRowMapper(new EmployeeRowMapper());
    return reader;
}
```

- **Note - Once above error appears, connection never gets establishesh
  with the datasource and I dont see any data is coming.**

Comment: When exactly does this issue happen? Please post the full stack trace, we can't see the root cause of the exception.

Comment: Hey, I've provided is th full stack trace, this happens while reading using `JdbcCursorItemReader` or `JdbcPagingItemReader` from Oracle DB.

Comment: No, that's not a full stack trace. We don't even see what the exception is nor its root cause (if any).

Comment: This is coming after enabiling trace logger level

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apparent connection leak detected with Hikari CP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883940/apparent-connection-leak-detected-with-hikari-cp)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - Hey If you look at my configuration I've used same configurations. In fact I already reffered link and put the same configuration while posting the question. Any help now please ?

Comment: Yeah, but does your query take more than `LeakDetectionThreshold`? If it's the case, then you are in the same situation as the duplicate question and you need to increase the threshold. How long does your query take to return results?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - Actually almost 20 batch jobs are already running and few of them are experincing this issue. Oracle DB is 11g. Query reads almost 20 millions records, JdbcCursorItemReader is taking time. What max values we can se here ?

Comment: I don't know what value you can use, it depends on how long your query takes to return, but it should be greater than the query time to avoid this issue as explained in the duplicate question.

Comment: This is a warning, did you try increasing leakDetectionThreshold? As previous comment if query is longer you should increase

Comment: Thank you for accepting, Was issue fixed by removing/reducing minimumIdle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Hikari feature that **warns** you about **possible** leakage,

For long running queries you should consider increasing [leakDetectionThreshold](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/hikari-cp/leakDetectionThreshold%7Csort:date/hikari-cp/d03eR_-RM88/y9TUAxpqAgAJ)  relative to your maximum query expected response time

> You can figure that out by using HikariCP leakDetectionThreshold parameter. Configure it to the duration of your slowest query + some small constant to avoid false positives.

You can also try to tune hikari pool by reducing [minimumIdle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51536716/how-to-restrict-initial-pool-size-in-hikaricp)

> to limit the life of idle connections

For *reputable source* you can ask your question in [HikariCP discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/hikari-cp)